# How to list how many iterations of a struct are stored inside a vector?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ (and coding in general) and have recently been working with a struct held inside a vector, in this case :

```
struct Contact{
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;
    string email;};

vector<Contact> contacts;
```

So, one of my functions involves searching through each of the contacts to find the one for which the string stored in name matches a search input. To do this I made a for loop as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
    if(contacts[i].name == searchInput){
        cout << contacts[i].address << "\n\r" << contacts[i].phone << "\n\r" << contacts[i].email;
```

But for some reason this was only able to find the correct contact if it was the name stored at:

```
contacts[0].name
```

and none of the others. So while trying to figure out what was wrong, I decided to do

```
cout << contacts.size();
```

which I thought should output 3, because I have only three contacts stored. Yet for some reason, it output 7. Is there anyway for me to accurately list the number of iterations of Contact stored in the contacts vector in order to get my for loop to work?

Edit for my full code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Contact
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;
    string email;
};

bool go;
bool a = false;
char command;
string endL = "\n\r";
string tab = "\t";
string line;
int i;
int counter = 0;
int contactCounter = 0;
vector<Contact> contacts;

void add(){
    contacts.push_back(Contact());
    int newcontact = contacts.size() - 1;
    string input;
    cout << "Enter the name: " << endL;
    cin >> input;
    contacts[newcontact].name = input;
    cout << "Enter the address: " << endL;
    cin >> input;
    contacts[newcontact].address = input;
    cout << "Enter the phone number: " << endL;
    cin >> input;
    contacts[newcontact].phone = input;
    cout << "Enter the email address: " << endL;
    cin >> input;
    contacts[newcontact].email = input;
}


void search(string name){

    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        if(contacts[i].name == name){
            cout << "Name: " << contacts[i].name << endL << "Address: " << contacts[i].address << endL << "Phone Number: " << contacts[i].phone << endL << "Email: " << contacts[i].email << endL << endL;
            a = true;
        }
    }
    if(a == false){
        cout << "There is no contact under that name." << endL;
    }
}

int main() {
    ifstream phonebook;

    phonebook.open("phonebook.txt");

if(phonebook.is_open()){
    while(getline(phonebook,line)){
        if(line.empty() == false){
            if(counter % 4 == 0){
                contacts.push_back(Contact());
                contacts[contactCounter].name = line;
            }else if(counter % 4 == 1){
                contacts[contactCounter].address = line;
            }else if(counter % 4 == 2){
                contacts[contactCounter].phone = line;
            }else if(counter % 4 == 3){
                contacts[contactCounter].email = line;
                contactCounter++;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    }else{cout << "an error has occurred while opening the phonebook";}
   phonebook.close();
   cout << contacts.size() << endL;
    cout << "Enter a command." << endL << tab << "To add a contact, enter '+'" << endL << tab << "To search for a contact, enter 's'" << endL << tab << "To delete a contact, enter '-'" << endL << tab << "To quit the program, enter 'q'" << endL;
    cin >> command;

    while(command != 'q'){

        if(command == '+'){
            add();
            command = '/';
        }
        else if(command == 's'){
            string searched;
            cout << "Please enter who you would like to search for: ";
            cin >> searched;
            search(searched);
            command = '/';
        }
        else if(command == '-'){
            cout << "Not done." << endL;
            command = '/';
        }
        else if(command == '/'){
            cout << "Enter a command." << endL << tab << "To add a contact, enter '+'" << endL << tab << "To search for a contact, enter 's'" << endL << tab << "To delete a contact, enter '-'" << endL << tab << "To quit the program, enter 'q'" << endL;
            cin >> command;
        }

        else{
            cout << "That command is invalid." << endL;
            cout << "Enter a command." << endL << tab << "To add a contact, enter '+'" << endL << tab << "To search for a contact, enter 's'" << endL << tab << "To delete a contact, enter '-'" << endL << tab << "To quit the program, enter 'q'" << endL;
            cin >> command;
        }


    }

    ofstream newbook;
   newbook.open("phonebook.txt");
   if(newbook.is_open()){
        for(int i=0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
            newbook << contacts[i].name << endl;
            newbook << contacts[i].address << endl;
            newbook << contacts[i].phone << endl;
            newbook << contacts[i].email << endl;
            newbook << endL;
        }
   }else{cout << "there was an issue saving your contacts" << endL;}
    newbook.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your complete code?

Comment: In your add() function change the location `contacts.push_back(Contact());` to the end and instead of for example `contacts[newcontact].name = input;` work on the Contact() struct and then add this to the vector. Also in your search if `a` gets true, it seems like it never gets false.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually nothing wrong with your code except this line

```
string endL = "\n\r";
```

Which should really only be

```
string endL = "\n";
```

`\n` is automatically converted to the line endings used by the system, which traditionally is `\n (0x0a)` on unix systems and `\r\n (0x0d0a)` on Windows.

But, how did this affect the program so much? Well it only takes affect after the phonebook is written at the end of the program so that `phonebook.txt` contains these bogus line endings that have `\r\n\r` at the end (on Windows). So when the file is read, it reads up until the new line `\r\n` and sees `\rPerson Name` as line after! Which explains why searching was failing.

You also may see some additional bogus contacts generated because there may be some extra `\r`s at the end which read as a single line each. Without looking at your `phonebook.txt` I can't say for certain why you have an additional 4 though I'd guess extra `\r`s would be the cause.

All in all, use `\n` for new lines.

To answer the title, `vector::size()` is THE way to get the number of stored objects in a vector. It's not lying to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the range based for loop ensures that you won't hit any nonexistent contacts:

```
for(auto&& contact: contacts)
{
    // Contact contact is now accessible.
}
```

Also, it is probably not a good idea to store `a` as a global variable. What happens if you execute `search` twice?

Comment: thanks for the call out on the a variable, that would have messed me up. As for the ranged based for loop, I haven't had much experience with it. Would you mind explaining what each part of the code you wrote means syntactically? Cause I'm afraid I don't know how to apply it right now.

Comment: @WilderLedes `for(auto&& contact: contacts)` is the shorthand of `for (auto it = contacts.begin(); it != contacts.end(); ++it) { auto& contact = *it; }`